# jQuery start function when previous is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 5  text node like

```
<h2 class="textillate"> test </h2>
<h2 class="textillate"> test </h2>
<h2 class="textillate"> test </h2>
<h2 class="textillate"> test </h2>
<h2 class="textillate"> test </h2>
```

I want to textillate these nodes one by one when the previous is finished.

i tried this but didn't make it :(

```
$(document).ready(function() {
nodes = $('.textillate');
nodes.eq(0).textillate()
.eq(1).textillate();
});
```

Comment: use the [each jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method

Comment: not familiar with a textillate plugin, but it probably accepts a callback method, which is what you should use to force the next one to fire only upon completion of the current.

Comment: Your selector is wrong: your class is `textilate` (one 'l'), your selector is `.textillate` (2 'l').

Comment: @MikeW just a miss typo, not present in my code but thx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with function parameters, namely `initialDelay`. For example this does the trick:

```
nodes = $('.textilate');
nodes.each(function(index, element){
      $(element).textillate({initialDelay: index*1000});
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LUq39/

Take a look at more [usage options](https://github.com/jschr/textillate) to more finelt adjust the various durations.

**UPDATE**

Here is an updated demo that depends on length of the string: http://jsfiddle.net/LUq39/13/ it actually accumulates delay time:

```
var nodes = $('.textilate');
var delay = 0
nodes.each(function(){
      delay += $(this).prev()? $(this).prev().text().length*50:0;
      $(this).textillate(
          {initialDelay: delay, in:{delay:50}, out:{delay:50}}
      );
})
```

Comment: I can't because i don't know how much time will last the animation because i can't get in advance the length of node value

Comment: I beleive this can be controlled by in/out delays

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look

Comment: Yeah this looks better hack because you are taking account of length of the text to set the initial delay and +1

Answer (score 0):

How about a jQuery [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.textillate').each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).textillate();
    });
});
```

As you want the functions to be executed one after another, why not just a for loop:

```
var items = $('.textillate')
for(var i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    $(items[i]).textillate();
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLHeadingElement> has no method 'textillate'

Comment: $(element) but I think it will apply effect simultaniously

Comment: I got an option to hack it, probably based on their options, posted below

Answer (score 0):

As I could understand, you want to wait for one textilate to end to call the next one.
I just read Textillate API and it has no callback/promise option.

As textillate does not provide a callback mechanism, it is impossible to know precisely when an animation ended. Unless you knwo the duration of each animation, you can wait for one to end to call the next one.

If you want to apply Textillate to each element at the same time, just use:

```
$('.textillate').textillate();
```

Comment: It makes my five node textillate at the same time :/